How to calculate the diameter of a set in $\ell^{2}$
He had studied functional analysis in the book "Lectures on Functional Analysis and the Lebesgue Integral" by V. Komorkik. On page 9 there is an example of properties in finite-dimensional spaces that do not hold in infinite-dimensional spaces.
For example, the diameter of a bounded and closed set is finite, but maximizers do not exist.
How can I calculate the diameter of $A$ given by:
\begin{equation*}
A:=\left\{x\in\ell^{2} : \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2}|x_{n}|^{2} \leq 1\right\}.
\end{equation*}
My idea is, given $x\in A$, we note that $-x\in A$ (since the constraint defines a set symmetric about the origin). So it turns out that
\begin{align*}
            \operatorname{diam}(A) &:= \sup _{x,y\in A} \|x-y\|_{2} \\
            &= \sup _{x\in A} \|x-(-x)\|_{2} \\&= 2\sup _{x\in A}\|x\|_{2} \\
            &= 2\sup _{x\in A} \left[ \sum _{n\in\mathbb{N}} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2}x_{n}^{2 } \right]^{1/2} = 2.
        \end{align*}
However, we note that there does not exist $x\in A$ such that its norm allows reaching the supreme, that is, given that for all $x\in A$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
            \|x\|_{2} < \left[ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2}x_{n}^{2} \right]^{1/2} \leq 1,
        \end{eqnarray*}
Therefore the supreme one that is studied in the calculation of the diameter is not reached. But, I'm not sure of the reasoning.
Regards!

take a large $n$ and then consider $x_n=n/(n+1), y_n=-n/(n+1), x_k=y_k=0, k \ne 0$ so $x,y \in A$ and $||x-y||=2n/(n+1) \to 2, n \to \infty$ so the diameter is at least $2$ and it's easily seen to be at most $2$ since $A$ is included in the unit ball

Ohhh, thank you!

When asking such questions, please explain everything, like: what is $\ell$? :-)

In general if $a_n$ satisfies $\inf|a_n|=r,$ then the diameter is equal $2r^{-1}.$

Thanks!! I will ask a more robust question.

@Conrad Your comment should rather be an answer,

Turning my comment into an answer: take a large $n$ and consider $$x_n=n/(n+1), y_n=-n/(n+1), x_k=y_k=0, k \ne n$$ so $x,y \in A$ and then $||x-y||=2n/(n+1) \to 2, n \to \infty$ so the diameter is at least $2$.
Since $A$ is included in the unit ball of $\ell^{2}$ the diameter is at most $2$ so it is indeed $2$ and we are done.
